# RTTI using Composition

Tags: oop, inheritance, composition, rtti

It is said that programmers should prefer composition over inheritance. I was wondering if RTTI can be achieved as easily using composition?

Comment: What does composition have to do with `typeof(T)`?

Comment: I am talking about Run Time Type Identification/ runtime polymorphism.

Comment: What exactly is the scenario you face? This question is far too broad - the short answer is "yes", does that help?

Comment: Show me a sample code to achieve RTTI using composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: RTTI is not "achieved" using inheritance. RTTI is an ability of a programming language. In C#, use `typeof(T)` or `.GetType()` or any other form of reflection. In C++, use `typeid`.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps I understand your problem now, although I believe you are coming at it from the wrong angle. In an inheritance tree you can check the type of an object using RTTI, whereas with no inheritance tree (using composition instead) there is no need because you will only have one possible type. You can then set up properties or methods to indicate the 'type' of your object, although in true OOP you should not need to check a type, rather you should let polymorphism deal with it.

In a composite object, method calls are forwarded to its children; in an inheritance tree, method calls are virtual and are handled by derived classes.